# Cannot convert object of type 'list' to a numeric value

Tags: random, numbers, typeerror, pyomo

I am making a pyomo model, where i want to use random numbers for my two dimensional parameters. I put a small python script for random numbers that looks exactly what i wanted to see for my two dimensional parameter. I am getting a `TypeError: Cannot convert object of type 'list'(value =[[....]]` to a numeric value. in my objective function. Below is my objective function and random numbers script.

```
model.obj = Objective(expr=sum(model.C[v,l] * model.T[v,l] for v in model.V for l in model.L) + \
            sum(model.OC[o,l] * model.D[o,l] for o in model.O for l in model.L), sense=minimize)

import random
C = [[] for i in range(7)]
for i in range(7):
     for j in range(5):
        C[i]+= [random.randint(100,500)]
model.C = Param(model.V, model.L, initialize=C)
```

Please let me know if someone can help fixing this.

Comment: It's generally more helpful if you include the full error message.

Comment: sorry the list was too long to copy paste

Comment: No worries, man. Glad you got it worked out. You should accept the answer below with the checkmark.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, I am very new on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should initialize your parameter using a function instead of a nested list

```
def init_c(m, i, j):
    return random.randint(100,500)
model.c = Param(model.V, model.L, initialize=init_c)
```

Comment: Hi Bethany, I have changed my param as random numbers but my solution is infeasible for some reason. I am getting ValueError: No value for uninitialized NumericValue object T[1,1] but T[v,l] is a binary variable and i already defined my variables in the beginning.

Comment: def Constraint1_rule(model, v, myDim):
    return sum(model.SOD[o,myDim] * model.A[o,v] for o in model.O) <= model.B[v, myDim] * model.S[v]
model.Constraint1 = Constraint(model.V, model.MyDim, rule=Constraint1_rule)

Comment: This is my first constraint that is using random number of param model.sod and model.b and they are both multiplying with binary variables. Can you please tell me why i am getting this error/

Comment: Could you post this as a separate question and include your entire model? The constraint you included in your comment does not include T so I don't think it's the problem. Without seeing the entire model I can't know if your model should be feasible for every possible combination of the random parameter values.

Comment: I changed the calibration of my random numbers and it gave me a feasible solution. The T[v,l] binary variable is in objective function that is multiplying with Cost (random param). I think that was the problem, other constraints are linked to each other that further are associated with my objective function.It was not picking any value for T variable in objective function, results in-feasibility. I really appreciate your quick response and thanks for your help. i will ask separate question next time, for now this worked :)